# MSSQL Query Optimization Without Expensive Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

We are developing a query to try and find all messages in a table that have their most recent Message Event be in Error. The messages can be re-processed and that has the potential to put them in a good state which is why we are looking for the most recent even to be the one in error. We are not strong with our SQL and the query we are currently running takes much longer than we would like to run. Is there anything outside of adding indexes or shrinking the table size that could help this query run faster? Can this be done without a join?

```
SELECT M.MessageID AS MessageID, 
       Source, 
       IntakeTimestamp, 
       MessageKey, 
       MessageSourceID, 
       CustomerID, 
       AgreementID, 
       LocationID, 
       EquipmentID, 
       OfficeID, 
       IncidentID, 
       M.HistoryID AS HistoryID, 
       Subject, 
       FromHeader, 
       ToHeader, 
       PackedHeaders 
FROM [pipe].[Message] AS M 
  JOIN [pipe].[MessageState] AS MS ON MS.MessageID = M.MessageID 
WHERE MessageStateID IN ( 
  SELECT TOP 1 MessageStateID FROM [pipe].[MessageState] AS NMS 
  WHERE M.MessageID = NMS.MessageID 
  AND MS.EventStatusID = 6 
  ORDER BY MessageStateID DESC ) 
ORDER BY [MessageID] DESC
```

I was able to pull all the messages in the error state with the simple query below but this didn't check the most recent message state only

```
SELECT * FROM [pipe].[Message] 
WHERE MessageID IN (
  SELECT *
  FROM [pipe].[MessageState] 
  WHERE EventStatusID = 6
  )
```

Comment: how do older rows differ from the most recent row ? Does only the IntakeTimeStamp and MessageStateID differs or also other columns ?

Comment: The IntakeTimestamp is when the message was received, not when it was processed so that will also be the same. The only thing that will change is the MessageStateID and the EventStatusID.

Comment: This can not be answered without a query plan. Please edit it - execute in SSMS, get the query pan, put it i.e. on https://www.supratimas.com/ - without knowing HOT it executes, we can not see what is wrong. One thing I see is the subquery - TOP 1.... you can run that as WHERE EXISTS, not WHERE IN, then remove the Top 1.

Comment: Ah, rather ue https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ - that can get you a link that contains the plan.

Comment: Working on doing that now. Thank you

Comment: I haven't even see a query plan before @TomTom. Thank you for the advice. I see that the join isn't even the issue, it's just the massive size of the table, even though the column is indexed. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the below to find the most recent record for each         `MessageID`, assuming that your `MessageStateID` ordering is appropriate for your data.  This works by assigning each group of rows with the same `MessageID` value a row number that is sorted in descending order by the `MessageStateID` value.  In doing this, any record with a `rn` value of `1` is the most recent record for that `MessageID`:

```
WITH m AS
(
    SELECT M.MessageID, 
           Source, 
           IntakeTimestamp, 
           MessageKey, 
           MessageSourceID, 
           CustomerID, 
           AgreementID, 
           LocationID, 
           EquipmentID, 
           OfficeID, 
           IncidentID, 
           M.HistoryID AS HistoryID, 
           Subject, 
           FromHeader, 
           ToHeader, 
           PackedHeaders,
           MS.EventStatusID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M.MessageID ORDER BY M.MessageStateID DESC) AS rn
    FROM [pipe].[Message] AS M 
      JOIN [pipe].[MessageState] AS MS
        ON MS.MessageID = M.MessageID
)
SELECT m.*
FROM m
WHERE m.rn = 1
    AND m.EventStatusID = 6
ORDER BY m.MessageID DESC
```

---

I would also recommend that you properly alias all your columns so you know which table they are coming from.